# Patch a Java class inside a jar using C#

Tags: java, hex, patching, jar, c#

Being a beginner in **C#** I wonder if it is possible to patch a ***.class*** file inside a **.jar**?

Since jar files tend to act like "zip" files, the approach I think might work is to decompress the jar, **patch the hex offset** in the *.class then zip back the jar and overwrite the original.

Any examples or tutorials showing how to do this? is there a better approach?

Comment: I don't think that makes much sense. Just extract the data, modify, and reinsert it.

Comment: Where is the connection between Java and C# in this question? And if this is a C# question, how is it RCE-related?

Comment: @0xC0000022L If I understood you comment; the connection is that I need to patch a class inside a jar file! not an exe file nor an image file... why C# because the app I'm developing is written in C#. Why; because I want to learn C# :).
Second thing; It is related to RCE because I'm "patching" an offset adress rather than modifying the original code.. maybe I should have put it in the main stackoverflow forum but I taught it belong to this forum.

Comment: If you were writing the app in Java you could have used the ***[BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/)*** library. However, you could use ***[IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html)*** to use the java library from C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

1. Decompile the content of the JAR, make your changes to the decompiled source code, recompile the sources, and rebuild the JAR. This works well if the CLASS files aren't obfuscated or overly complex.
2. As you answered in your question, you could extract the CLASS, hex edit it to make your changes, and add it back into the JAR with a tool like WinZip, WinRAR, or 7-zip.
3. Use the Java Virtual Machine Tools Interface to dynamically patch the program at runtime.

Unclear from your question what this has to do with C#, though.

Comment: In the title; Patch a Java class inside a jar using C#. Maybe I should have posted this question in another forum.. Anyway I found the solution. Thanks

Comment: After reading your answer at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3744/1562, it sounds like your question was a software development question, not a reverse engineering question.

Comment: I think that too, I was mislead by the forum titles.. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem. I'll leave the answer up in case someone in the future asks the question I thought you were asking ;)

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27606/Opening-Jars-with-C) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217732/how-to-edit-a-binary-files-hex-value-using-c-sharp) about patching class files inside jars using the [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) library.